# Sort GROUP BY agregats

Tags: mysql, group-by

Imagine this table `t1`,

```
+----------+-------+--------+
| group_id |  name |  age   |
+----------+-------+--------+
|    1     |   A1  |   1    |
|    1     |   A2  |   2    |
|    1     |   A3  |   3    |
|    2     |   B1  |   4    |
+----------+-------+--------+
```

Using the following query in MySQL,

```
SELECT group_id, name, COUNT(*) FROM t1 GROUP BY group_id
```

we get,

```
+----------+-------+--------+----------+
| group_id |  name |  age   | COUNT(*) |
+----------+-------+--------+----------+
|    1     |   A1  |   2    |    3     |
|    2     |   B1  |   4    |    1     |
+----------+-------+--------+----------+
```

As you can see here, it's possible that values name=A1 and age=2 are not from the same record.

---

My question is, how can I control which single results form the `name` and `age` columns are shown, so the content is from one record? Is there a way to sort them in some way? Fro example sorting by age in reverse order would give

```
+----------+-------+--------+----------+
| group_id |  name |  age   | COUNT(*) |
+----------+-------+--------+----------+
|    1     |   A3  |   3    |    3     |
|    2     |   B1  |   4    |    1     |
+----------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why do you say that your query works. You should also group by name...

```
SELECT group_id, name, COUNT(*) FROM t1 GROUP BY group_id, name
```

If you want to get only one of them, try:

```
SELECT group_id, MIN(name), COUNT(*) FROM t1 GROUP BY group_id
```

Comment: In MySQL my query should work.he problem is that I want data from one record.

If you use MIN(), the second other column might contain a value from a different record.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_id, name, COUNT(*)
FROM t1 
WHERE name IN ( 'xxx', 'yyy', ..., 'zzz' )
GROUP BY group_id
SORT BY COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about full control, but you can do like this

```
SELECT student_name, MIN(test_score), MAX(test_score)
        FROM student
        GROUP BY student_name;
```

Comment: This will not sove the problem :(

Comment: PLease give some more details, what you need as a result? maybe try just add ORDER BY count(*) ?